# JMeter Load Tesing::Moving from WebDriver sampler To JSR223 sampler with groovy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter, load, jsr223

I'm a newbie in jmeter so accept my apology for asking basics and long post.
My Ultimate goal is to do Load and stress testing for a ajax enabled  application (IBM Maximo if any one cm across it)

Till now I was working in Jmeter WebDriver Sampler(selenium) and I was very comfortable with it and enjoying it thoroughly.

Now I cm across this [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter). So I decided to move on JSR223 Sampler and groovy (2nd approach as described in article)..
Now here is My questions List :)

1. Is my decision is in right direction.should i move from Webdriver Sampler.
2. Is JSR223 sampler is one solider army or it work with http Request Sampler.
3. Is it able to handle Ajax request.
4. Can any one share how a test plan structure looks like if it use JSR223.
5. any videos tutorials on this topic(new bee on JSR233,as i m unable to find).
6. What are the Major areas JSR223 sampler can be used.

Thanks for keeping patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you would like to continue using WebDriver Sampler you can just write the code in Groovy, just make sure to choose it from the "Language" dropdown

   [image]
2. If you would like to simulate the load using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers instead you can simulate AJAX requests using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Comment: thnks Dmitri for quick response.   but even webdriver+groovy Consumes a lot of CPU/RAM .is it prefer condition in Load Testing.  Still i have same question,why we need to Use JSR223 sampler.

Comment: @Dmriti i need ur help on this